# How to tokenize an algebraic expression in Rust

Tags: regex, rust, token, tokenize, calculation

I am making a simple calculator that can evaluate an expression entered in the string form (ex. "1 + 2 / ( 0.5 + 0.5 )").

For the calculation part, I am using a postfix converter that feeds into a postfix calculator and I have no problems there.

The problem I am having is how to make a list of tokens (numbers, parentheses, operations) from a string that *doesn't* contain any spaces.

This is my method for doing it with spaces (if there is a better way to write this kind of code, please do tell):

```
fn parse_expression(expression: &str) -> Option<Vec<Type>> {
    let mut tokens = Vec::new();

    let types = [
        Regex::new(r"[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?").unwrap(), // numbers
        Regex::new(r"[+\-*/]").unwrap(),                                 // operations
        Regex::new(r"[()]").unwrap(),                                    // parentheses
    ];

    for token in expression.split_whitespace() {
        if types[0].is_match(token) {
            tokens.push(Type::Number(token.parse().ok()?));
        } else if types[1].is_match(token) {
            tokens.push(Type::Operation(token.parse().ok()?));
        } else if types[2].is_match(token) {
            tokens.push(Type::Parentheses(token.parse().ok()?));
        }
    }

    Some(tokens)
}
```

And my Type enum is defined as:

```
pub enum Type {
    Number(f64),
    Operation(char),
    Parentheses(char),
}
```

I tried `.split_inclusive`, checking character by character, regex lookahead (not supported in Rust).

Comment: Try this here: https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/

Might fit your use case much better than using regexes

Comment: I'd anchor the regex to the start (e.g. `^[a-z]+`), then repeatedly trim_start (to remove whitespace from the left) + regex match all tokens + remove the matched prefix from the string. Another way would be to use a parsing library like @cadolphs mentioned.

Comment: Note that regex lookahead can be emulated with capture groups. E.g. search with [`Regex::captures`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures) for `(expression)(lookahead)`, then use [`caps.get (1)`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.get) to retrieve the "useful" part of the match.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions which surely would work but I am more interested in how it's done theoretically without libraries and complex regex, rather than making a full blown calculator.

Comment: There are countless ways to write parsers/state machines, so no good way to answer the question.